# PHP correct company name format

Tags: php, format

I have company names like:

- Wal-Mart Stores, Inc
- Exxon Mobil Corporation
- Chevron Corporation
- Berkshire Hathaway Inc.
- Apple Inc.

and lot more.

I need to take a possibly misformatted company name as input, like:

```
interational Business Machines inc
```

and give the properly formatted name as an output, like

```
International Business Machines, Inc.
```

How can I achieve this in php? By matching input variable with all others? I need something that can help me to get started

Comment: Can you not loop through all the company names and use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: why not i loop through all company names ?

Comment: What is your definition of "formatted" and "misformatted" company names?

Comment: if it is interational Business Machines inc make it International Business Machines, Inc.

Comment: So you want camelcase?

Answer (score 0):

Loop your array of company names and use ucwords to make them camel case.

```
foreach($arr as &$name){
     $name = ucwords($name);
}
unset($name);
```

[ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example shows that you need something more than just proper capitalizing (like adding commas or may be removing unnecessary hyphens). So I'd do the following:

1. build a "common format" in which you can convert both properly formatted and misformatted titles. I think the best one is all-lower-case letters + no syntax (substitute with spaces);
2. convert your input to the "common format", like

   ```
   interational business machines inc
   ```
3. for each of the known titles, convert to the "common format" and if it's the same as your converted input, output that title

So, 1:

```
function convertToCommonFormat($input) {

    $lowerCasedInput = mb_strtolower($input,'UTF-8');

    // substitute with spaces, don't remove, otherwise Wal-Mart will become WalMart
    // while Wal Mart will remain Wal Mart, so they won't match
    $clearedInput = preg_replace('/[,\.\-]/',' ',$lowerCasedInput); // add more symbols to the regexp, if there can be some.. may be !, \? should be added as well

    // since "Machines, Inc." will become "Machines  Inc ", you have to deal with it
    $clearedInput = preg_replace('/ +/',' ',$clearedInput); // shrink more than 1 space
    return preg_replace('/ $/','',$clearedInput); // trim a space in the end
}
```

and 2-3

```
foreach($knownNames as $name)
    if(convertToCommonFormat($input) == convertToCommonFormat($name))
        return $name; // known company
return $input; // or null to point that the company is unknown
```

or better

```
$inputInCommonFormat = convertToCommonFormat($input);
foreach($knownNames as $name)
    if($inputInCommonFormat == convertToCommonFormat($name))
        return $name; // known company
return $input; // or null to point that the company is unknown
```

Comment: hy thanks for answer i already solved this by similar_text() function and by using its percentage value i have figured it out. i appreciate your answer too

Comment: @Awais that's an interesting option, I'll read more. I suggest you either post your own answer or accept the most helpful one and leave your solution as a comment

Comment: @Awais and you still should lower the case before using `similar_text` to improve similarity: `similar_text('HP','hp') == 0`